# Paho python client doesn't work properly with Mosquitto Broker

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to use paho python library provided by Eclipse to connect to Mosquitto server in order to publish and subscribe messages. Currently, I have Mosquitto daemon running and I am able to publish and subscribe and brokers finely directs topics. My problem is once I try to use the Paho library, I can connect to the Mosquitto server (broker) but I can't receive topics I subscribed for. Both publisher and receiver code works fine but there might be some thing I am missing. I will be thankful if someone helps me.

My publisher/subscriber codes are as follows:

Subscriber:

---

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+ str(rc))
    client.subscribe("test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Recieved message " + str(msg.payload) + " " + msg.topic + "Qos= " + str(msg.qos))
    client.disconnect()

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_massage = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

---

Publisher:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
client.publish("test", "Hello World!")
client.disconnect();
```

Comment: typo - `client.on_massage = on_message` should be `client.on_message = on_message`

Answer (score 1):

Your publisher is not waiting for the connection to complete before trying to publish and then disconnecting again without waiting to allow the publish to complete.

You have 2 options

1. Use the same pattern as the subscriber and put the `publish` in the `on_connect` callback to ensure the connection is complete before trying to publish.
2. Use the single publish [short cut](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#single) function that is included in the Paho library

e.g.

```
 import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

 publish.single("test", "HelloWorld", hostname="localhost")
```

EDIT:

Also a bunch of typo's in your subscriber

```
client.on_massage = on_message
```

should be `client.on_message`

Also all the `message` should be `msg` and `pyload` should be `payload`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Let me tell you the issue in another way. Both my publisher and the shortcut you provided are capable of publishing their message. My problem is when I subscribe for the message to retrieve with "mosquitto_sub" command from my Ubuntu Terminal, I can retrieve it but my subscriber above is not capable of receiving it from the broker. This is confusing me right now.

Comment: Typo in your subscriber code, `client.on_massage` should be `client.on_message` (also you should set the callbacks before calling `connect`)

Comment: What a shame. I apologize for your time. Thank you so much. Problem Solved.